# Acceder a objecto JSON sin saber el nombre en PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de acceder al source de thumbnail, pero el pageid cambia dinamicamente y no encuentro la forma de acceder a el.
Estoy trabajando con PHP y de esta manera accedo a los recursos de el API de Wikipedia

```
$wikipediaArticleImage = $wikipediaArticle['query']["pages"][36408]["thumbnail"]["source"]
```

En donde el pageid `[36408]` cambia dinamicamente dependiendo del artículo buscado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: en qué lenguaje deseas acceder a él? sería mejor que lo pusieras como código en vez de imagen

Comment: @Sr1871 Cierto lo olvíde, acabo de actualizar

Comment: Soy daltónico y no puedo ver el código de tus imágenes. De todas maneras esta es una página sobre código, no sobre capturas de pantalla ¿Por qué poner capturas en lugar de código? ¡es más complicado! y no se puede copiapegar el código de una imagen ni hacer búsquedas de texto; por favor: PON EL CÓDIGO, NO IMÁGENES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente puedes iterar sobre todos los elementos

```
foreach($wikipediaArticle['query']["pages"] as $pageId => $data) {
   $wikipediaArticleImage = $data['thumbnail']['source'];
}
```

Ten en cuenta que si tienes más de un page, este código traerá la imagen del último page, si quieres la primera, pon una break

```
foreach($wikipediaArticle['query']["pages"] as $pageId => $data) {
   $wikipediaArticleImage = $data['thumbnail']['source'];
   break;
}
```

Si quieres guardar todas ponlas en un arreglo

```
$wikipediaArticleImages = [];
foreach($wikipediaArticle['query']["pages"] as $pageId => $data) {
       $wikipediaArticleImages[] = $data['thumbnail']['source'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podés obtener el id de esta forma. Es el valor que queda en $key cuando haces loop.

```
$pages = $wikipediaArticle['query']["pages"];
foreach ($pages as $key=>$value){
    echo 'En la pagina ' . strval($key) . ' esta el source: ' . $pages[$key]["thumbnail"]["source"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu codigo es en java, puede usar algo similar a esto

Lo metes en un jsonElement, extraes el objeto json, y luego lo seralizas a Json, y al final iteras cada objeto para obtener el listado.

```
private JsonElement jsonTickets;

         Response<JsonElement> response = call.execute();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                jsonTickets = response.body();

                if (jsonTickets.getAsJsonObject().size() > 0) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonTickets.toString());
                    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

                    mTickets = new ArrayList<>();

                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        String key = keys.next();
                        Ticket itemTicket = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get(key).toString(), Ticket.class);
                        mTickets.add(itemTicket);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Si es en C#, con un simple `JArray`

Comment: Lo siento olvíde específicar el lenguaje que es PHP, pero gracias por tu ayuda